# What triggers Visual Studio to say "A matching symbol was not found in this folder"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-dump

I'm working on a memory dump, but out of the hundreds of symbol files, I don't know which one I can use for mapping to the dump (I always get the message `A matching symbol was not found in this folder` using `Modules`, `right-click`, `load symbols`).

This means that Visual Studio is verifying some property/parameter/... of the dump file, some property/parameter/... of the PDB file, and in case both don't match, the mentioned error message is shown.

Does anybody know what property/parameter/... of dump and symbol file are verified for deciding to show this error message? (Once I know this, this might help me searching for the right symbol file)

Thanks in advance